# Using Interface class in form, in order to use the derived class desired

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I would like to use different custom widgets on the same area (that depends on the situation). For that I created an Interface class and some derived custom classes widgets (because they have same methods and for the cleanliness).

My Interface is :

> IDial

Derived Classes :

> FirstDial, SecondDial

These derived classes inherit from IDial, so they have common functions from IDial.

When I start my program, I would like to chose which dial I will display, it depends of macros or parameters (it's not important).

In order to be able to display the derived class (widget) that I want, I have no other choices than put the Interface class name (IDial) as "objectName" of my widget area in the form (design mode).

The problem is that Qt is trying to instantiate this Interface... (it's impossible and normal because of pure virtual functions).

I would like to indicate that the area can contain different widgets, which all inherit from this Interface.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @ddriver Ok, I'll try to explain better

Comment: Post a working minimal example.

Comment: @ddriver I tried to improve my explanation, hope you understand.

Comment: Your explanations don't say anything to me, maybe it is just me though, I am not a very good programmer, maybe those are concepts too advanced for me ;) Post your code, then we can actually see and understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of class IDial, add QFrame to the place where you want. In your header file:

```
#include "firstdial.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>
...
QHBoxLayout* layout;
FirstDial* firstDial;
```

In source file create new layout and object of your class:

```
ui->frame->setFrameShape(QFrame::NoFrame); // a frame you've created
layout = new QHBoxLayout(ui->frame);
firstDial = new FirstDial;
```

Add your widget to layout:

```
layout->addWidget(firstDial);
```